# Converting date format using str_to_date

Tags: mysql, date-format

In one of my Mysql database table the dates are stored in the format 31-Jan-05.
I'm trying to convert this format to 2005-01-31 before inserting them in other tables.
I've tried in this way `str_to_date(exam_date, '%d%M%Y')`, but i encounter the following error

```
Incorrect datetime value: '31-Jan-05' for function str_to_time
```

Can't i change the date format from 31-Jan-05 to 2005-01-31 using str_to_date?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But you have two problems.

1. The second parameter is the *current* date format. (i.e. of the string)
2. You need to have the proper format (i.e. `%b` instead of `%M`).

Read the [docs the for `str_to_date()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

```
str_to_date(exam_date, '%d-%b-%y')
```

**Note:** If you don't have a zero padded day, then you need to use `%e` instead of `%d`.

Comment: i've tried again with `str_to_date(exam_date, '%d%b%y')` and still got the same error

Comment: As Jason says, check the docs for str_to_date. It's asking for the format of the *passed in date*, and it can't be "close enough", it has to be the same - including any dashes or slashes or whatever.